# How to populate a collection with new objects, copying properties from another collection

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

Let's say I have two classes:

**Foo:**

```
public class Foo {    
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }    
}
```

**Bar:**

```
public class Bar {
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}
```

So, `Bar` doesn't need an Id property. What I want to do is create a new collection of `bar` objects from an existing collection of `Foo` objects - there should be one `Bar` created for each `Foo`. Each `Bar` would have the `Name` and `Type` from the `Foo` that it was created from.

I know this will need to look something like this, but not quite sure how to complete it:

```
IEnumerable <Foo> foos = queryResults; //I'll get my foo's with a LINQ query
IEnumerable <Bar> bars = new IEnumerable<Bar>();

foreach (Foo f in foos) {
    //create a new Bar and add it to bars
}
```

Please point me in the right direction!

Comment: `new IEnumerable <bar>();` - you can't do this. You need to instantiate a concrete type like a `List<bar>`. Then you just need to do `bars.Add(new bar { Name = f.Name, Type = f.Type });` in your `foreach`.

Comment: Also, try and observe [C# naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx). They are important if you ever plan to collaborate.

Comment: Good point on the naming conventions, I can see already that it caused confusion below! I'm picking up programming after a break so just forming good habits again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List<Bar>` instead of `IEnumerable <Bar>`, and assign the properties of `Bar` using its constructor as below

```
IEnumerable <Foo> foos = queryResults; //I'll get my foo's with a LINQ query
List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();

foreach (Foo f in foos) {
    bars.Add(new Bar() { Name = f.Name, Type = f.Type });
}
```

Comment: This won't compile (`Bar` must be lower-case)

Comment: Just trying this out now, thanks. Will let you know how I get on

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `Linq` query:

```
IEnumerable <bar> bars = foos.Select(x => new bar{Name = x.Name, Type = x.Type});
```